# Why does justify-items cancels 1fr in grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

Let's consider the following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="longText">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet and so on !</div>
  <div class="otherContent">*</div>
</div>
```

The `.container` has a min-width of 500px, and the `.otherContent` takes exactly 350px.

`.longText` needs to be displayed on the left of `.otherContent`, it cannot be smaller than 150px, and if the text is too long, it needs to make an ellipsis.

The ellipsis part is easily managed by the famous combo `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;`.

There are many ways to solve the positioning. Let's use `display: grid;` with `grid-template-columns: minmax(150px, 1fr) 350px;` on the `.container`.

This works nicely.

However, if I add `justify-items: start;` on `.container` then the display breaks: when the text is too long, the `.longText` does not reduce, and so the ellipsis is not created ([jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rwdfvygz/1/), reduce the size of your browser to see the left div overlapping the right one).

```css
.container {
  min-width: 500px;
  border: 1px #f00 solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(150px, 1fr) 350px;

  justify-items: start;
}

.longText {
  border: 1px #00f solid;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.otherContent {
  height: 50px;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px #0f0 solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="longText">
    Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet and so on !
  </div>
  <div class="otherContent">
  *
  </div>
</div>
```

Why does `justify-items` has this effect ?

Comment: because the default value is stretch

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, I understand why it does work when I don't add it, what I don't get is why the `start` value has this effect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this simply add `max-width:100%`

```css
.container {
  min-width: 500px;
  border: 1px #f00 solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(150px, 1fr) 350px;

  justify-items: start;
}

.longText {
  border: 1px #00f solid;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width:100%;
}

.otherContent {
  height: 50px;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px #0f0 solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="longText">
    Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet and so on !
  </div>
  <div class="otherContent">
  *
  </div>
</div>
```

For the why, it's because the default value is `stretch` so the element don't need a `width` or `max-width` and will stretch to fill all the area.

You can find more details in [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-item-sizing):

> stretch
>
> Use the inline size calculation rules for non-replaced boxes (defined in [CSS 2 §10.3.3 Block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#blockwidth)).

> all other values
>
> Size the item as fit-content.

So any other value different from stretch will give you a `fit-content` width creating the overflow unless you explicitely define a `width`/`max-width` or you use `stretch`.

As a side note, the `1fr` is not canceled and the column width is the same in both case. Only the width of the element inside the column is changing.